# Loopback 4 validation returns 422 unexepcted, plus how to require only one of three properties

Tags: loopbackjs

1. My application accepts three different types of phone numbers for a model. I'd like to validate the numbers to match a certain pattern only if that number is not empty. I've tried this in declaring the properties, but it causes a 422 because it's trying to apply the validation even when a number isn't present. Is there a way to apply the pattern only when the property is not empty?

```
  @property({
    type: 'string',
    jsonSchema: {
      maxLength: 14,
      pattern: "[(][0-9]{3}[)] [0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}",
    },
  })
  cell_phone: string;
```

2. I'd also like to make sure that at least one of them is not empty. It's not clear from the documentation (or I just completely missed it, which has happened) if this is possible outside of checking for at least one of them in the controller. Is there a way to declare this in the model?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using `getModelSchemaRef` in your controller which means you could make the property optional by doing something like this

```
getModelSchemaRef(ModelClass, { optional: ["cell_phone"] })
```

Comment: Not explicitly, if I am at all. I'm handling files, too, so I am doing the validation like so:
`await validateValueAgainstSchema(application, jsonToSchemaObject(getJsonSchema(Application)));`

Answer (score 0):

Alrighty, maybe not the most pretty, but this works.

The phone number properties are defined as so:

```
    type: 'string',
    jsonSchema: {
      oneOf: [
        {pattern: "[(][0-9]{3}[)] [0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}"},
        {maxLength: 0},
      ],
    },
  })
  home_phone?: string;

  @property({
    type: 'string',
    jsonSchema: {
      oneOf: [
        {pattern: "[(][0-9]{3}[)] [0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}"},
        {maxLength: 0},
      ],
    },
  })
  cell_phone: string;

  @property({
    type: 'string',
    oneOf: [
      {pattern: "[(][0-9]{3}[)] [0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}"},
      {maxLength: 0},
    ]
  })
  other_phone?: string;
```

Then I just check to make sure the correct phone number is set in the controller, like so:

```
    if (application[primaryPhoneType] === '' || typeof application[primaryPhoneType] === 'undefined') {
      throw new HttpErrors.UnprocessableEntity('The primary_phone_type is set to ' + application.primary_phone_type + ' but ' + primaryPhoneType + ' was empty.');
    }
```